# D3 the x axis positions in wrong way

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart

I have run into problem of displaying the chart X axis which is translated in wrong position. Here is my example http://jsfiddle.net/staar2/Vww3h/1/.

As you can look from the html inspector the svg elements get translated wrong. What I think the xScale are set wrong.

```
var data = JSON.parse('[{"hour":0,"time":147},{"hour":1,"time":0},{"hour":2,"time":74},{"hour":3,"time":141},{"hour":4,"time":137},{"hour":5,"time":210},{"hour":6,"time":71},{"hour":7,"time":73},{"hour":8,"time":0},{"hour":9,"time":68},{"hour":10,"time":70},{"hour":11,"time":0},{"hour":12,"time":147},{"hour":13,"time":0},{"hour":14,"time":0},{"hour":15,"time":69},{"hour":16,"time":67},{"hour":17,"time":67},{"hour":18,"time":66},{"hour":19,"time":0},{"hour":20,"time":0},{"hour":21,"time":66},{"hour":22,"time":210},{"hour":23,"time":0}] ');

  var w = 15,
      h = 80;

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, 1])
      .range([0, w]);

  var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
          return d.time;
      })])
      .rangeRound([5, h]);

  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(xScale)
      .orient("bottom")
      .ticks(5);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(yScale)
      .orient("left");

  var chart = d3.select("#viz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("class", "chart")
    .attr("width", w * data.length - 1)
    .attr("height", h);

  chart.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return xScale(i) - 0.5;
    })
    .attr("y", function(d) {
      return h - yScale(d.time) - 0.5;
    })
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", function(d) {
      return yScale(d.time);
    });

  chart.selectAll("text")
   .data(data)
   .enter()
   .append("text")
   .text(function(d) {
      if (d.time > 10) {
        return Math.round(d.time);
      }
   })
   .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
   .attr("font-size", "11px")
   .attr("fill", "#FFF")
   .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
   .attr("x", function(d, i) {
        return xScale(i) + w / 2;
   })
   .attr("y", function(d) {
        return h - yScale(d.time) - 0.5 + 10;
   });

  chart.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h) + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: You're setting the domain of the x scale to be `[0,1]` but it looks like you're expecting it to be `[0,data.length-1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `xScale` domain and range as well accordingly, as

`xScale
  .domain([0, data.length-1])
  .range([0, w*(data.length-1)])`

while you call `xScale(i)` where `i` is the index of data element, as far as i understood, and so the domain should be between `0 - data.length`.